# div inheriting cursor style from underlying div

Tags: css

I have this problem I can't solve,
I'm trying to add a zoom-in/out cursor to some divs on a site
the .l image has a nice zoom-in cursor, upon click, a new .esc div is loaded (as a lightbox)

```
.l{
cursor: -webkit-zoom-in; cursor: -moz-zoom-in;
}
.esc {
 cursor: -webkit-zoom-out; cursor: -moz-zoom-out;
}

#media{
 cursor:default;
}
```

suppose that the #media div is contained inside the .esc div. the #media div has some areas in which there's literally nothing, and in those areas the mouse cursor is not :default, but -webkit-zoom-out.

I still haven't found a way to override this problem, any idea?

```
-------------------------
|.esc                   |
|    ----------------   |
|   |  #media       |   |
|   | -----  ---    |   |
|   | |   | |   |   |   |
|   | |   | |   |   |   |
|   | |   | -----   |   |
|   | |   |    *    |   |
|   | |   |         |   |
|   | -----         |   |
|    ----------------   |
-------------------------
```

* here it should be cursor:default; but it's -moz-zoom-out

here's a jsfiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/mmbFu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok check it out, look through your code and look for these lines:

```
               <a href="/random.php?media=media" style="color:#91BD09">RANDOM</a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Its very near the bottom, and that last div? Thats the closing tag for your #media.
Now do this:

```
               <a href="/random.php?media=media" style="color:#91BD09">RANDOM</a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Insert that div and it will always clear other elements according to the normal flow of the page. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Seriously? Post up or JSFiddle your code, that should set the cursor to its default.

Comment: Does the cursor know its over #media? Set #media's z-index:1000;

Comment: I'll try in a few hours. I'll let you know

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `#media` is smaller than its contents (give it a visible background to verify). This happens if the contents are given `float:left` or `float:right`

There are several ways to make a container expand to its contents:

- add an invisible element to the end of `#media` and give it `float:none; clear:both`.
- set the container to `overflow` other than `visible` (`hidden` or `auto`).

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that your div#media has the same height/width as the two blocks inside? So the div covers the whole area, might have to add float:left to make it inherit the size of the child objects.

It would be easier to fix with a jsfiddle as @George said.

Comment: Please don't float an element just to make it expand to its children (then you'd have to float its parent, it's grand-parent... Soon you'd be building a flotsam, not a web page)